# Gridview is not displaying

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

I have added a gridview in my Visual Studio project. The gridview is set to visible. After deploying the project the `GridView` is not displayed, but I don't know why. What can be the problem? I feel really confused.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you binding any data to the grid view ?

gridView1.Datasource = MyDs/MtTable...

gridView1.DataBind();

> If you are using any UpdatePanels with UpdateMode = Conditional, then
>   after above code, use

MyUpdatePanel.Update()

> Is your data source having any records ?

You can check the source.Rows.count (or similar properties)

> Did you set AutoGenerateColumns ?

Try adding custom columns